# Pull to Refresh RecyclerVIew Adapter not working

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have searched lot of times on google that how to refresh recycler view after pull the swipeRefreslayout but code did not work

This is my code

```
 swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                refresh();
            }
        });
        return r;
    }

    private void refresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, "refresh called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fragment.RefreshList(String.valueOf(adpterposition));
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }
        }, 3000);
    }
```

This is my refreshlist function in fragment

```
public void RefreshList(String catego) {
        parser = new ParseDataClass(getContext(), recyclerview, swipeRefreshLayout);
        parser.execute("http://192.168.100.12/fetchtext.php", catego);
    }
```

Another method applied

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                refresh();
            }
        });

    }

    private void refresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               // refreshEvents(OutletsData1);
                MyRecyclerAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }
        },3000);
    }
```

I am new to android I am not adding more data in adapter but I want when I refresh recycler view if internet is available my list should be refresh again if internet is not available my recycler view should be null or empty due to refresh.

Please guide me how can I do it ?

Comment: I think you can use swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true); inside onRefresh() Method.

Comment: where is your `SwipeRefreshLayout` in `fragment` or `activity`?

Comment: in fragment ...but swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener implementing in recycler view adapter

Comment: @MajidAli why is it ? why are you implementing `setOnRefreshListener` in `adapter` instead of **Fragment** itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want when I refresh recycler view if internet is available my list should be refresh again if internet is not available my recycler view should be null or empty due to refresh.

To do this, I think you should clear the data of recycler view as soon as you try to refresh it and add new items only when you get actual  data. In this way if you have no internet then your recycler view will be empty and as soon as you get your connectivity back refresh it to get new data

Comment: so how can I clear the previous data and refresh it with actual ?

Comment: if you are using arraylist as data source for recycler view then call arraylist.clear() and then call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter to clear the previous data and display it. To get the refreshed data send api request again and and as soon get the data add them to the arraylist and again call notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

you can use the swipe layout

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
         swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       RefreshList();
                    }
                });

   }

 @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
              refresh();
        }



 private void refresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                RefreshList();
               // refreshEvents(OutletsData1);

             swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        },3000);
}


 private void RefreshList() {
     //clear your list before any update
    //here fatch the data ....
    //on success or failture
MyRecyclerAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

**This is my adapter code**

```
 public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<DataStored> 
      outletsData,SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout) {
        this.c = c;
        OutletsData = outletsData;
        OutletsData1 = outletsData;
        this.swipeRefreshLayout = swipeRefreshLayout;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singleitem,null);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder=new MyViewHolder(view);

        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mBrandName.setText(OutletsData.get(position).getMbrand_name());
        holder.branchAddress.setText(OutletsData.get(position).getMbranch_address());
        holder.discountTxt.setText(OutletsData.get(position).getMdiscount_amount());
        holder.mBrandName.setText(OutletsData.get(position).getMbrand_name());

        holder.setItemClickListner(new ItemClickListner() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                Toast.makeText(c,OutletsData.get(position).getMbrand_name(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(c,DetailOfListCard.class);
                intent.putExtra("brand_name",OutletsData.get(position).getMbrand_name());
                intent.putExtra("branch_logo",OutletsData.get(position).getMbranch_logo());
                intent.putExtra("brandlogo",OutletsData.get(position).getMbrand_logo());
                intent.putExtra("branch_address",OutletsData.get(position).getMbranch_address());
                intent.putExtra("position",MainActivity.adapterPosition);
                c.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return OutletsData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(customFilter==null){
            customFilter=new CustomFilter(this,OutletsData1);
        }
        return customFilter;
    }
```

Comment: but what about recycler view adapter ?

Comment: I mean should I use these function in fragment oncreate?

Comment: where is your adapter ? This is the code of swipe layout that is use in activity , It will update your adapter . show me your adapter.

Comment: don't need to implement in recycler view adapter?

Comment: check edit answer , i have make on create method of fragment.

Comment: Don't use swipe layout in adapter , make simple adapter , remove swipe layout . whenever swipe call you adapter automatically notify . all swipe related work is done on fragment.

Comment: Please tell me how can I remove previous data and refresh with actual data? would I send again api to server to get actual data?

Comment: check update , your adapter is edit , and clear the list before update.